# How to temporarily disable the Escape key in a Terminal?

Tags: bash, text-processing, terminal

I am parsing keyboard input via `read -n 1` and I haven't found a way to distinguish between an actual key-press of the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key and the first Escape character (byte) of a control sequence generated by some other key-press, eg. <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>RIGHT</kbd>...

I don't need the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key during the `read`, so disabling it should solve the problem.  Is there some way to disable or re-assign just the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key in a localized manner? ...for just the current terminal, and for just the current script.

Comment: note: ncurses uses a timer to distinguish the two (see `man 3x notimeout`/timer), not sure if it is able to disable the escape key completely.

Comment: Stephane: Thanks, It's useful to know that a timer is a tried-and-tested method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this from inside the terminal. Unfortunately, the same `ESC` character sees use both as the character sent by a particular key on the keyboard and as the prefix in multi-character sequences. The historical precedents on both sides are too strong to be overwhelmed.

Applications either avoid giving a meaning to <kbd>Esc</kbd> alone, or put a delay (1 second is common). For example, in vim, go into insert mode and press `ESC O D` very quickly; this is equivalent to pressing the <kbd>Left</kbd> key. But if you wait too long after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, you'll switch to normal mode and insert a line above the current one (`O` normal mode command).

You might be able to reconfigure your terminal emulator so that the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key sends some escape sequence other than the `ESC` (`\e`) character. But that's likely to be backfire if you run an application that uses the `ESC` key intensively, such as vi(m).

Comment: Gilles, as you and Stéphane have both pointed out, the prevailing method appears to be to use a 'timer', so I've added a simple nanosecond timer... It works quite well, as the generated key sequences hit the script loop faster than I can type.. It may glytch occasionally due to system load, so I'm, including  option for a speed check. Thanks... (that's quite interesting about vim.)

Answer (score -1):

If you’re on a Mac, then I can heartily suggest the following pair of tools:

- [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html#t1), a utility to remap the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key to anything else,
- and [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html), another (more complex) utility by the same hacker to remap almost any *other* key (i.e. not <kbd>caps lock</kbd>)

Combined, I remap <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and completely disable the actual <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (it’s so far “out there,” and using my remapped caps-lock key is a much better habit to be getting into.)